# Ipad. image view height and width fixed on rotation

Tags: ios, ipad, interface-builder

Xcode 4.6.3 Ipad development.

I have an image view which i rezied to width:300 Height: 300 in landscape mode.
But when i rotate to portrait the width and height totally change, how can i make sure the width and height stay the same?

Thank you.

Comment: imageView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

Comment: Where in the code should this go?

Comment: can you attach your screenshot or code?

Comment: Change the Center of the image not the frame

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in autoresizing mask. Make sure that you have not set `UIViewFlexibleHeight` either in IB or in code.

Comment: Where can i check that exactly?

Comment: How have you added image view? I mean using IB, Storyboard or code?

Comment: Open xib Show Size Inspector and check autoresizing there. Or check constraints if you use them.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following code when your view did load

```
[yourImageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
yourImageView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
yourImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

It will not allow imageView to resize it self when ever the screen changed to landscape to portrait or vice versa.